# Nginx: site can not be accessed due to certs problem

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am self-hosting `poste.io`, which use nginx as underlying web server.

my certs were got from let's encrypt just few days ago.

in chrome, it shows `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`, while in firefox: `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`

same certs works for other reverse proxy(istio). ngxin version: 1.18.0

I got following files from let's encrypt:

- privkey.pem -> used as server.key for nginx
- cert.pem
- chain.pem -> used as server.crt for nginx
- fullchain.pem

I can't update nginx, becuase it's version is locked by `poste.io`, please help.
nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

ssl.conf:

```
    # https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&server-version=1.17.0&config=intermediate
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
    
    resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
    
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:32m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/administration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /opt/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /admin {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /webmail {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /doc {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }
    location /autodiscover {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }
    location /mail {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /policy {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/www/policy/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dh4096.pem;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    root /opt/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost mail.* discover.* autoconfig.*;

    location ~ ^/webmail/(config|temp|logs|CHANGELOG|INSTALL|README\.md|LICENSE|UPGRADING|.htaccess|composer\.json|composer\.lock|composer\.json-dist)/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /doc {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /autodiscover {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /mail {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location /api {
        return 301 https://$host/admin$request_uri;
    }

    location = /admin {
        return 301 /admin/;
    }

    location ~/admin/haraka/(\d+)/ws {
        auth_request .auth;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~/admin/haraka/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
        auth_request .auth;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1/$2;
    }

    location /admin/rspamd/ {
        auth_request .auth;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "";
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:11334/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location .auth {
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:443/admin/auth-ws;
    }

    location /admin {
        alias /opt/admin/public;
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location /dav {
        alias /opt/admin/public;
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/z-push/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        # Z-Push Ping command will be alive for 470s, but be safe
        fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
    }

    location @app {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm-admin.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/admin/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     /admin/index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

### Edits:

error in nginx log:

```
2023/10/17 16:07:48 [info] 21125#21125: *447 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201076:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:no suitable signature algorithm) while SSL handshaking, client: 172.30.9.49, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Comment: You need to actually configure nginx to use the certificates - the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` settings are missing from your config. See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it is in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/administration`, which was included by nginx.conf

Comment: And use (certbot's) fullchain.pem not chain.pem .  cert.pem is the server/end-entity cert and chain.pem is the intermediate -- maybe still plus the bridge for Android compatibility; they announced they are finally dropping that but I don't recall exactly when. nginx wants BOTH the EE and intermediate(s) in that order in one file, and that's fullchain.pem . Also check your log(s); it should have complained about 'key does not match cert' or something like that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are life saver ! use `fullchain.pem`  as `server.crt`  fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Use (certbot's) fullchain.pem not chain.pem

Nginx wants **both** the end-entity certificate and intermediate(s), in that order, in one file. That's `fullchain.pem`.

Also check your log(s); it should have complained about '`key does not match cert`' or something like that.